# Drupal and TinyMCE + Filemanager WYSIWYG

Tags: php, drupal, tinymce, wysiwyg

I installed the WYSIWYG module on my Drupal 6 site, and I'm using TinyMCE.
This works fine.

Now I want to add the filemanager plugin from TinyMCE, how to do this?

I added the filemanager folder to `/sites/all/libraries/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins`
and changed this:

`$mcFileManagerConfig['authenticator'] = "DrupalAuthenticator";`
in the config.php

But what now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE plugins in WYSIWYG modules are config in sites/all/modules/wysiwyg/editors/tinymce.inc, 
in function: wysiwyg_tinymce_plugins($editor).
You can  define one plugin  by implement hook_wysiwyg_plugin(), like:

```
'font' => array(
  'path' => $editor['library path'] . '/plugins/font',
  'buttons' => array('formatselect' => t('HTML block format'), 'fontselect' => t('Font'),     'fontsizeselect' => t('Font size'), 'styleselect' => t('Font style')),
  'extended_valid_elements' =>     array('font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]'),
  'url' => 'http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/font',
  'internal' => TRUE,
```

),

Comment: thanks I'll try this if I'm home. How do I know what 'buttons' to use?